# RewriteRule for first folder in URL only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have to redirect some folders from my domain to a subdomain. These are my .htaccess rules:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /folder1  http://sub.domain.com/folder1$1
RedirectMatch 301 /folder2  http://sub.domain.com/folder2$1
```

All working well, this redirects everything from

```
www.domain.com/folder1/... => to => sub.domain.com/folder1/...
```

But what is the world without challenges? I recognized this problem: this rules also redirect

```
www.domain.com/sub1/sub2/folder1/... => to => sub.domain.com/folder1/...
```

and in my case this is not good. Any solution to avoid this?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delimite your regex pattern using **^** and **$** to match just **/folder1** .

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder1$ http://sub.domain.com/folder1$1
```

Comment: Hi starkeen, I tried this, but it doesn't work, it's the same as before. This also is redirecting www.domain.com/sub1/sub2/folder1/... => to => sub.domain.com/folder1/... As I understand, the ^ marks the first apperance, so I updated the question text. Because I only want to redirect folder1 if it is the first folder after the domain. In an url like www.domain.com/sub1/sub2/folder1/ it is still the first appearance, but in this case it shouldn't be redirected.

Comment: Perhaps it's because of your browser cache. Clear caches and retest it.

Comment: This f****** cache ;-) It works, but I receive an error because the redirect-url looks like this: http//sub.domain/folder1/ (missing ":" )

Comment: I dorped the **$** after folder1 and it works. Can you update your answer?